# How to get the general term for a quartic sequence really need help

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, polynomials, lagrange-interpolation, quartics

Is it possible to find the general term for a quartic sequence and if so how do you do it?
The sequence I am using is 1,9,36,100,225,441, 784, 1296, 2025, 3025
I am only interested in finding the general term in the form ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2....
Even if you can`t give an answer could you please tell me if it's even possible
Thank You

Comment: Well, you can write this out for five of your values and solve the associated system of equations.  You could also use Lagrange interpolation.

Comment: Sorry I have no clue what you are talking. Could you please elaborate.

Comment: @Cooldude can you find the general term for a quadratic sequence? If so, how do you think this would extend to a quartic sequence?

Comment: Yes I can for a quadratic but I don`t even know how to start on quartic

Comment: could you like sub in the values 1 into x and then solve

Comment: e.g. a(1)^4+b(1)^3+c(1)^2+d(1)+e = 1

Comment: @Cooldude yes, moreover this is lulu's first suggestion. If substitution is the only method you know for quadratics then it is the only method we can really suggest for quartics. If you know other methods, then you need to tell us what those are and explain how you think they extend to quartics.

Comment: could I factorise the equation into 2 quadratics and then solve for the quadratics

Comment: See "Differences" at https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2C9%2C36%2C100%2C225%2C441%2C+784%2C+1296%2C+2025%2C+3025+

Comment: Or note that the numbers are the squares of $1,3,6,10,15,\dots$, the triangular numbers

Comment: @Cooldude (re: factorising into 2 quadratics) not in general, unless you are prepared to use complex numbers. In this case, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the difference table (mentioned by @lhf in a comment), the leftmost column implies formula
$$1\binom{x}{0}+8\binom{x}{1}+19\binom{x}{2}+18\binom{x}{3}+6\binom{x}{4},$$
which simplifies to
$$\frac{1}{4}x^4 + \frac{3}{2} x^3 + \frac{13}{4} x^2 + 3 x + 1.$$
If your first sequence element corresponds to $x=1$ instead of $x=0$, then shift the formula:
$$\frac{1}{4}(x-1)^4 + \frac{3}{2} (x-1)^3 + \frac{13}{4} (x-1)^2 + 3 (x-1) + 1 = \color{blue}{\frac{1}{4}x^4 + \frac{1}{2}x^3 + \frac{1}{4}x^2} = \left(\frac{x(x+1)}{2}\right)^2.$$

Comment: How come this does not result in $\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$?

Comment: @martycohen Because of ambiguity of whether the index starts at $0$ or $1$.  If you substitute $n-1$ in place of $x$, you will get your proposed formula.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it might be something like that since your answers are usually correct and perceptive.

Comment: Hey thank you so much for the help but I was wondering if it is possible to get an equation for this in the form of ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2+ dx + e or is this the only equation that works for this sequence

Comment: The middle part (now in blue)  of the last display shows it in that form.

Comment: You can add $0x+0$ if you need to.

Comment: Thank you so much this helps a lot.

Comment: Im sorry this may sound a bit silly but what does the x over the 0 in brackets mean

Comment: It is a binomial coefficient: $\binom{x}{k} = \frac{x!}{k!(x-k)!}$.  In particular, $\binom{x}{0}=1$.

Comment: Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

Say f(x)=ax⁴+bx³+cx²+dx+e. This is the general form of a quartic polynomial. From the information you've given, f(1)=1, f(2)=9, f(3)=36, f(4)=100, and f(5)=225. Substitute in these values instead of x and you'll have five equations and five unknowns which should be pretty easy to solve. Then, using the values you get for a,b,c,d, and e, you can get the formula for the nth term of the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at this,
the terms are

$1^2, 3^2, 6^2, 10^2,
15^2, 21^2, 28^2,
36^2,
45^2, 55^2
$
which are the
squares of the triangular numbers
or
$\left(\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2
=\dfrac{n^2(n^2+2n+1)}{4}
=\dfrac{n^4+2n^3+n^2}{4}
$.